# Cocos2d 2.0 instance method not found; reciever is a forward class

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, methods, cocos2d-iphone

My GameScene.m file :

```
#import "GameScene.h"

// Needed to obtain the Navigation Controller
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#pragma mark - GameScene

// GameScene implementation
@implementation GameScene

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
{
    [self addChild:[GameLayer node]];
}
return self;
}


- (void) dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

@end
@implementation GameLayer
@synthesize hero;

-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init] )) 
{
    hero = [[Hero alloc] initWithGame:self];
}
return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

My GameScene.h file :

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

// When you import this file, you import all the cocos2d classes
#import "cocos2d.h"

// GameScene
@interface GameScene : CCScene 
{
}

@end

@class Hero;

@interface GameLayer : CCLayer
{
Hero * _hero;

NSMutableArray * _bullets;
bool _playerFiring;

NSMutableArray * _enemies;
float _lastTimeEnemyLaunched;
float _enemyInterval;

int _score;
int _lives;
int _bombs;
int _level;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) Hero * hero;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) bool playerFiring;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) float lastTimeEnemyLaunched;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) float enemyInterval;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray * enemies;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray * bullets;
@property (assign,readwrite) int score;
@property (assign,readwrite) int lives;
@property (assign,readwrite) int bombs;
@property (assign,readwrite) int level;

@end
```

My Hero.h file :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@class GameLayer;

@interface Hero : CCNode
{
CCSprite * mySprite;
GameLayer * theGame;
float _lastTimeFired;
float _fireInterval;
float _firingSpeed;
float _movementSpeed;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) CCSprite * mySprite;
@property (nonatomic,retain) GameLayer * theGame;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) float lastTimeFired;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) float fireInterval;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) float firingSpeed;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) float movementSpeed;

@end
```

And my Hero.m file :

```
#import "Hero.h"

@implementation Hero

@synthesize theGame,mySprite;

-(id) initWithGame:(GameLayer *)game
{
self = [super init];
if(self != nil)
{

    // ask director for the window size
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    self.theGame = game;
    mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"hero.png"];
    [theGame addChild:mySprite z:2];
    [mySprite setPosition:ccp(size.width/2,50)];

    self.lastTimeFired = 0;
    self.fireInterval = 3;
    self.firingSpeed = 10;
    self.movementSpeed = 5;

}
return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And here's my problem : I get two warnings - 1. "instance method -initWithGame not found (return type default to 'id')" and 2. "Receiver 'Hero' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist"

I tried to add "-(id) initWithGame:(GameLayer *)game" line to Hero.h interface, but it won't work. I tried to add that line but with + instead of -, but nothing.

I end up without my Hero displayed on a screen. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem (I use newest version of Xcode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GameScene.m`, you should

```
#import "Hero.h"
```

This explains why you get the "forward class" warning: since you did not import the header, the only thing known to the compiler in the GameScene compilation unit is the forward declaration.

Once you do that, if you also declare `initWithGame` in Hero.h, then you won't get any warning.

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon hanging in the air :P

Comment: Hello. I added "#import "Hero.h" in GameScene.m. I got rid of error "Receiver 'Hero' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist". But that second error still exists, and prevents my sprite to show up. What to do?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't possibly clear enough: you should also declare your initWithGame method in the .h file.

Comment: Thanks, all errors disappeared. But The sprite is not showing up. Can you tell me why?

Comment: It seems to me that you are not adding your sprite as a child to the layer anywhere. Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your original problem.